# Math.ceil to increase a number does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Does anyone know other solution than below, to be able to increasing speed by value of score?

In my vuex application I have this getter:

```
   getters: {
    speed: state => Math.ceil(state.score / 5) || 15
  }
}
```

The speed should increase every 5th score

This is not the case, as {{ speed }} doesn't change from 15. Imported it like so:

```
       computed: {
      ...mapGetters('playerData', {
        speed: 'speed'
      })
    },
```

Comment: What is the value of `state.score` ?

Comment: Since 0 is falsy, `0 || 15 === 15`. So your result will always be 15 if `state.score` is in the interval `]-5;0]`